# When I use React_component, View_Helper provided by Gem called react-rails in Rails5, the contents of div become empty without reloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-rails

I use react with Rails 5 using Gem called React-Rails.
However, although the component of react is loaded using ViewHelper called react_component, the contents of the div will be empty when the page is transitioned.
However, reloading will create the contents of the div.

I will explain in the code.

index.html.erb

```
<%= react_component('Hoge') %>
```

Hoge.js

```js
import React from "react"

class Hoge extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="row">hello</div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default Hoge
```

The contents of the HTML when the page is transitioned are as follows.

```html
<div data-react-class="Hoge" data-react-props="{}"></div>
```

There are no error logs in the browser and the Rails console.

When reloading this page

```html
<div data-react-class="Hoge" data-react-props="{}">
<div class="row">hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide complete code examples? I understand that omitting some verbose parts of your code can make it easier to skim through, but the problem could be in some of the details that you have left out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry. What you said was correct.
I write `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` application.html.erb in Head tag above turbolinks.
Thank you.